# Mono.Cecil - obfuscated malicious code

Tags: obfuscation, mono.cecil, deobfuscation

In this great article (http://eatplayhate.wordpress.com/2010/07/18/mono-cecil-vs-obfuscation-fight/), the author claims that Mono.Cecil is not perfect, but that it translated a good 90% of the functions without any issues.

My question to you guys is: Can an evil programmer obfuscate malicious code that could not be deobfuscated using Mono.Cecil and thus cause a serious breach in my program (3rd party code)?
If the answer is yes, do you know what symbols I can use to write such code, or how I can protect my self from such code?

Comment: Do you want to protect specifically against deobfuscation? or against obfuscation?

Comment: in my case I get 3rd party code that Im deobfuscated it

Comment: If you want to deobfuscate something, check this out: https://bitbucket.org/0xd4d/de4dot/ this is much better than mono-cecil whose purpose is not really obfuscation, it's just a mean to obfuscate

Comment: thank you for your answer
I still need an answer to the question I asked? can a talented programmer write malicious code that I would not able to deobfuscate?

Comment: Nope. de4dot deobfuscates anything known today. It may change in the future of course, but noone can predict the future.

Comment: I assume simply not trusting obfuscated code is not a solution for you?

Comment: Nop, I get this code from my clients

Answer (score 2):

Of course an evil programmer can always obfuscate code better than you can deobfuscate it. Determining the behavior of arbitrary code in advance is an undecidable problem after all.

More practically, the obfuscation vs deobfuscation fight is just over who puts in more effort. Obfuscation is much easier than deobfuscation, but commercial obfuscators tend to be much less sophisticated than what you can write by hand or with a custom obfuscator, for various reasons. The fact that Mono Cecil is good enough to debofuscate many common obfuscation tools doesn't mean it can do anything about the later.

If you want to see some of the tricks you can pull with hand obfuscated code, take a look at [this crackme](http://www.crackmes.de/users/warsaw/java_crackme_3/). It's Java bytecode rather than CLI, but the idea is similar. As of this writing, noone has even solved it, despite the crackme consisting of a single method in a single class. And it doesn't even use Reflection, the proper use of which makes automated deobfuscation all but impossible.

The real question however, is what you're trying to do with this. Are you trying to check arbitrary code for malicious behavior? Sorry, but that's not really possible. You need to run it in a sandbox.